# Why does AngularJs or javascript convert a 4 digit string as a date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, dapper

I am using `angularJs` and have a field stored in `MSSQL` as `varchar(10)`. The data is stored and displayed correctly so long as it isn't a 4 character number like `1234`.

When I save that string, the db has the correct value of `1234`, but when it is displayed in the UI, it looks like a date: `"1234-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"`

The html uses `{{project.PurchaseOrderNumber}}` to render the data.

`angularJs` code:

```
projectService.getProjects().then(function (response) {
    $scope.projects = response.data;
    $scope.loading = false;
}, function() {
    messageService.showError("Failed to get projects. Please refresh and try again");
});


service.getProjects = function() {
    return $http.get(baseUrl + 'API/Projects/');
};
```

`C#` code:

```
[Route("")]
public List<Project> GetProjects()
{
    return _projectService.GetProjects(_companyId.ToString());
}


public List<Project> GetProjects(string companyId)
{
    return _databaseHelper.QueryProc<Project>("projects_get", new { companyId }).ToList();
}


public class Project
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string PurchaseOrderNumber { get; set; }
}
```

`JSON` string as part of the response:

```
[{
    "Id": "daef5b27-fb8c-4804-a407-0165e17c3a60",
    "CompanyId": "76bca824-6e93-45a5-bc5a-ba20d030ebce",
    "Status": "New",
    "PurchaseOrderNumber": "1234-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
}, {
    "Id": "09d87946-dec2-4721-bf71-df436919b599",
    "CompanyId": "76bca824-6e93-45a5-bc5a-ba20d030ebce",
    "Status": "New",
    "PurchaseOrderNumber": "160728"
}]
```

`MSSQL` code:

```
SELECT [id]
        ,[companyId]
        ,[status]
        ,[purchaseOrderNumber]
    FROM [dbo].[projects]
```

Results in `SQL`
[image]

I have confirmed that prior to `GetProjects` returning the results, the `purchaseOrderNumber` is still `1234`. However, when I break at `$scope.projects = response.data;` it is in date format.

**UPDATE**

I just checked the Network tab in Chrome and see that the data is actually in the correct format, but when it is provided to `response.data` it isn't.

```
4:{Id: "daef5b27-fb8c-4804-a407-0165e17c3a60", CompanyId: "76bca824-6e93-45a5-bc5a-ba20d030ebce",…}
   CompanyId:"76bca824-6e93-45a5-bc5a-ba20d030ebce"
   Id:"daef5b27-fb8c-4804-a407-0165e17c3a60"
   PurchaseOrderNumber:"1234"
   Status:"New"
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have learned that this happens with any field. If it contains only 4 digits (any 4 digits, in any order), it is rendered as a date when it is provided to `angularJs`

Why does angular do this? How do I stop it?

Comment: Show us the source JSON and other relevant code. Angular isn't doing this on it's own. Create a demo that reproduces this

Comment: @charlietfl, I added the relevant code. Do you recommend a tool where I can create a demo that anyone can test?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue

Comment: The trouble with that service is I can't reflect where the issue happens. By the time the data is in `JSON`, it is a date. As I think about it, that must mean it is an issue in how dapper is converting it to `JSON`.

Comment: yup...exactly the point when you create  a demo. Seems very strange you have date and number being sent from server for same field

Comment: the db is returning the `varchar`, dapper is mapping it to a `String`, but if it is four digits, it thinks it should be formatted as a date first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118586/discussion-between-davids-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the input you are using is type="date" ?

You can print the variable as it is stored like this:

> {{project.PurchaseOrderNumber|raw}}

Comment: Here is the original input: `<input ng-model="project.PurchaseOrderNumber" ng-change="appData.changesMade=true" md-select-on-focus ng-disabled="!appData.ProjectAdminRole">`

Comment: changing it to raw didn't help

Comment: Could you print the Jain you have?

Comment: Or use the dump provided by angular so you know how the information is stored

Comment: I am not sure what Jain is, so I can't provide it. I updated the question to show how it is stored prior to angular.

Answer (score 0):

[Angularjs remove line of response data before JSON eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30548990/angularjs-remove-line-of-response-data-before-json-eval)

see the solution above and in your case the transformRespose would be

```
{
transformResponse : []
}
```

Now, once the transformResponse is set to null the success callback would be raw json instead of Objects like usual in angularjs.

Comment: I want to use a scalpel to remove the problem, not a hammer to kill it all. :) Is there a way to prevent angular from formatting the string as a date unless I specifically request it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are parsing JSON string to json object and converting date string to date object, you need to ignore 4 character value object to convert into date object

**Update**

I guess somewhere in your angular data service or controller you are parsing json string into JSON object and there is a logic to convert date string to date object written somewhere there.  T hat logic will have REGEX for ISODate , so You just need to improve that logic to not consider 4 digit string to match Regx.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. In my case I sent the data as a `number` via JSON to the frontend and angular interpreted it as a date. By changing the value to a `string` I was able to get it working properly.

But in your case maybe trying it the other way around works?